# How do we switch to another folder using terminal commands?

Tags: gnome-terminal

In olden days of DOS, we had cd command to switch folders.
The case does not seem same like DOS.
Please help

Comment: Keep in mind that Linux is not DOS, many commands are different, however cd is also the command to change directories in Linux, it should work (see Rakeshs asnwer).

Comment: and do not forget: {tab} does auto-complete.

Comment: And `cd` actually switch folders here too.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a dir named "apps", with templates, static as its contents.

```
cd apps
```

will enter you to apps folder.

```
cd apps/templates
```

will enter you to templates directory

```
cd ..
```

you will reach to the apps dir

```
cd
```

you will reach main directory

Answer (score 0):

you use the cd command , it stands for change directory.

the file system in linux is arranged in a tree beginning at the root or /  directory.

One catch to lookout for is that using the cd command is relative to where you are now in the file system , unless you start the path after the cd command with a /

3 handy commands for traversing the filesystem

- `cd path`   or  `cd /path/path`     to change directory
- `pwd` to display current directory you are in (present working directory)
- `ls`  to list the content of you current directory.